# bash: Reading a full record from a fifo

Tags: bash, read, fifo, ipc

I wish to send a command to process A, from process B, via a FIFO.

The command will be a word or a sentence, but wholly contained on a "\n" terminated line - but could, in general, be a multi-line record, terminated by another character.

The relevant portion of the code that I tried, looks something like this:

**Process A:**

```
$ mkfifo ff
$ read x < ff
```

**Process B:** *(from another terminal window)*

```
$ echo -n "cmd"   > ff
$ echo -n " arg1" > ff
$ echo -n " arg2" > ff
 ...    
$ echo    " argN" > ff
```

However, what's happening is, the `read` returns with the value `cmd`, even though the `bash` man page says it, by default, reads `\n` terminated lines, unless the `-d delim` option is used.

So, I next tried specifying `-d delim` explicitly,

```
$ read -d "\n" x < f`
```

and still the same result.

Could `echo -n` be closing the FIFO's file 'descriptor'?

I'm using bash 4.4.x on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, that's exactly what happens:

```
$ mkfifo p
$ while :; do cat p ; done > /dev/null  & 
$ strace -etrace=open,close bash -c 'echo -n foo > p; echo bar > p' |& grep '"p"' -A1
open("p", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
--
open("p", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
```

The redirections only take effect for the duration of the single command they're set up on. The workaround on the write side is to either a) use a compound block to group the commands, or b) use `exec` to open a file descriptor for the duration of the whole script (or until closed).

a)

```
{ echo -n foo; echo bar; } > p
```

(You could also put the commands in a function and use redirection when calling the function.)

b)

```
exec 3>p
echo -n foo >&3
echo bar    >&3
exec 3>&-         # to explicitly close it
```

If you want to fix it on the reading side, you'll need to loop over `read` and concatenate the strings you get. Since you explicitly want partial non-lines, and to skip over end-of-file conditions, you can't use the exit code of `read` for anything useful.